# How to pass Body Parameters to Post operation using API Management Action in Logic App?

Tags: azure, post, azure-logic-apps, azure-api-management

I need to consume API in Logic App using API Management Action. I added API Management Action to Logic App with Echo Create Resource (POST) operation. According to the screenshot below I can pass Authentication object and Subscription key only.

[image]

I figure out how to add Query Parameters in Swagger API description and use them in Logic App.

How can I pass Body Parameters to API Post operation using API Management Action in Logic App?

Comment: edit logic app workflow directly and append it?

Comment: I can see in API Management Action the fields for Authentication object and Subscription key only. See the screenshot. There is no Body field to append it. Where should I append it?

Comment: If the body parameters are described in swagger then the Logic Apps designer should discover them. Otherwise you can use code-view and edit the definition directly (add "body" property under the action inputs)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to consume the Echo API - I was able to reproduce. In this the POST operation has no body defined.
When I integrate one of my own APIs with a body definition I can see and use it in Logic App Designer

Sample

```
  /mail:
    post:
      operationId: Send Email
      parameters:
        - name: mailMessage v3
          in: body
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/MailMessage v3'
      consumes:
        - application/json
      responses:
        '202':
          description: ''
```